# Recuperar valor de label usando jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo la siguiente linea , Estoy usando esto para saber el id pero me da vació

```js
$(document).on('click', '.editRuta', function () {
  alert($(this).find('.id').text());
});
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class='list-group-item'>
 <label class="id" hidden>1</label>

 <div class='text_holder'> 
  Corriente
  <div class='btn-group pull-right'>
   <button class='deleteRuta btn btn-warning'>
    Borrar
   </button>
   <button class='editRuta btn btn-success'>
   Editar
   </button>
  </div>
 </div>
 <br />
</li>
```

Como puedo recuperar el valor del `label`justo en el botón que presiono, por ejemplo si presiono en la fila 3, que me recupere el id de la 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la estructura de su código tendría al menos dos opciones de búsqueda del `label`.

1.- Obtener el primer elemento padre  con [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) la clase `text_holder` y luego buscar el elemento hermano con [siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) para llegar al label con su clase `.id`.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.editRuta', function () {
 console.log($(this).closest('.text_holder').siblings('.id').text());
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class='list-group-item'>
 <label class="id" hidden>1</label>

 <div class='text_holder'> 
  Corriente
  <div class='btn-group pull-right'>
   <button class='deleteRuta btn btn-warning'>
    Borrar
   </button>
   <button class='editRuta btn btn-success'>
   Editar
   </button>
  </div>
 </div>
 <br />
</li>

<li class='list-group-item'>
 <label class="id" hidden>2</label>

 <div class='text_holder'> 
  Corriente
  <div class='btn-group pull-right'>
   <button class='deleteRuta btn btn-warning'>
    Borrar
   </button>
   <button class='editRuta btn btn-success'>
   Editar
   </button>
  </div>
 </div>
 <br />
</li>

<li class='list-group-item'>
 <label class="id" hidden>3</label>

 <div class='text_holder'> 
  Corriente
  <div class='btn-group pull-right'>
   <button class='deleteRuta btn btn-warning'>
    Borrar
   </button>
   <button class='editRuta btn btn-success'>
   Editar
   </button>
  </div>
 </div>
 <br />
</li>
```

1.- Obtener el primer elemento padre  con [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) la clase `list-group-item` y luego buscar el elemento hijo con [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) para llegar al label con su clase `.id`.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.editRuta', function () {
 console.log($(this).closest('.list-group-item').find('.id').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
<li class='list-group-item'>
 <label class="id" hidden>1</label>

 <div class='text_holder'> 
  Corriente
  <div class='btn-group pull-right'>
   <button class='deleteRuta btn btn-warning'>
    Borrar
   </button>
   <button class='editRuta btn btn-success'>
   Editar
   </button>
  </div>
 </div>
 <br />
</li>

<li class='list-group-item'>
 <label class="id" hidden>2</label>

 <div class='text_holder'> 
  Corriente
  <div class='btn-group pull-right'>
   <button class='deleteRuta btn btn-warning'>
    Borrar
   </button>
   <button class='editRuta btn btn-success'>
   Editar
   </button>
  </div>
 </div>
 <br />
</li>
<li class='list-group-item'>
 <label class="id" hidden>3</label>

 <div class='text_holder'> 
  Corriente
  <div class='btn-group pull-right'>
   <button class='deleteRuta btn btn-warning'>
    Borrar
   </button>
   <button class='editRuta btn btn-success'>
   Editar
   </button>
  </div>
 </div>
 <br />
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

El `.find()` te retorna una lista, aunque sea un solo ítem, para acceder a ese primer ítem se usa `.first()`:

```
$(document).on('click', '.editRuta', function () {
    alert($(this).find('.id').first().text());
});
```

Esto así aunque mejor, no funcionaría pues el `find()` llamado desde el `button` va a buscar dentro del `<button>` así que tendrías que escalar los padres del elemento para encontrar el `<label>` con clase `id`, esto se puede hacer con varios `.parent()` encadenados, subiendo un nivel a la vez ... o usando `.closest()`

```
$(document).on('click', '.editRuta', function () {
    alert($(this).closest('LI').find('.id').first().text());
});
```

Aunque si podes cambiar el HTML tal vez te convenga usar un atributo `data` y simplificar el asunto:

```
<li class='list-group-item' data-id="1">
<div class='text_holder'> Corriente
  <div class='btn-group pull-right'>
    <button class='deleteRuta btn btn-warning'>Borrar</button>
    <button class='editRuta btn btn-success'>Editar</button>
  </div>
</div>
<br />
</li>
```

---

```
$(document).on('click', '.editRuta', function () {
    alert($(this).closest('LI').data('id'));
});
```

Se puede poner el `data-id` en el `button` pero como hay otro `button` tendrías que repetirlo en ese también.